This expression is not callable. error for connectRedis in TypeScript
I have an error for this line of code
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

My error
This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof import("e:/farhad/my projects/New folder (2)/poker-game/node_modules/connect-redis/dist/connect-redis")' has no call signatures.ts

My code :
import { injectable, inject } from 'inversify';
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import { ILogger } from './../interfaces/ILogger';
import { COMMON_TYPES } from "../types/types";
import session from 'express-session';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);



@injectable()
class RedisManager {
    private redisMaster: Redis;
    private redisSlave: Redis;
    private redisStore: RedisStore;

    constructor(
        @inject(COMMON_TYPES.iLogger) private logger: ILogger 
    ) {
        this.redisMaster = new Redis({
            host: 'master-redis-host',
            port: 6379,
            db: 0,
        });

       
        this.redisSlave = new Redis({
            host: 'slave-redis-host',
            port: 6379,
            db: 0,
        });

        this.redisStore = new RedisStore({
            client: this.redisMaster, 
            ttl: 3600, 
        });

        this.redisMaster.on('connect', () => {
            this.logger.info('Connected to Redis Master successfully');
        });

        this.redisSlave.on('connect', () => {
            this.logger.info('Connected to Redis Slave successfully');
        });

        this.redisMaster.on('error', (err) => {
            this.handleError(err, 'Master');
        });

      
        this.redisSlave.on('error', (err) => {
            this.handleError(err, 'Slave');
        });
    }

    
    private handleError(error: unknown, source: string): void {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            this.logger.error(`${source} Redis error: ${error.message}`);
        } else {
            this.logger.error(`${source} Redis error: Unknown error`);
        }
    }

    public configureSession() {
        return session({
            store: this.redisStore,
            secret: 'your-secret-key', 
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            cookie: { secure: false }, 
        });
    }


    async setMaster(key: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.redisMaster.set(key, JSON.stringify(value));
            this.logger.info(`Data stored in Redis Master: ${key}`);
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError(error, 'Master');
        }
    }


    async getSlave(key: string): Promise<any | null> {
        try {
            const data = await this.redisSlave.get(key);
            if (data) {
                this.logger.info(`Data retrieved from Redis Slave: ${key}`);
                return JSON.parse(data);
            } else {
                this.logger.warn(`No data found for key in Redis Slave: ${key}`);
                return null;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError(error, 'Slave');
            return null;
        }
    }


    async getMaster(key: string): Promise<any | null> {
        try {
            const data = await this.redisMaster.get(key);
            if (data) {
                this.logger.info(`Data retrieved from Redis Master: ${key}`);
                return JSON.parse(data);
            } else {
                this.logger.warn(`No data found for key in Redis Master: ${key}`);
                return null;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError(error, 'Master');
            return null;
        }
    }


    async deleteMaster(key: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.redisMaster.del(key);
            this.logger.info(`Data deleted from Redis Master: ${key}`);
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError(error, 'Master');
        }
    }


    async deleteSlave(key: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.redisSlave.del(key);
            this.logger.info(`Data deleted from Redis Slave: ${key}`);
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError(error, 'Slave');
        }
    }
}

export default RedisManager;

